# AngularJS - $scope outsite $http

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http

I've create this piece of code:

```
app.controller('SiteDetailCtrl',function($scope, $routeParams, $http){
    //remove ":" in SiteId
    var SiteId = $routeParams.SiteId.replace(':','');

    $scope.Site = $http.get('path-to-ajax/Site/'+SiteId);
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.Site = data;
            console.log($scope.Site);
        })
        .error(function(){
            $scope.Site = 'NULL';
            alert('Ajax Fail');
        });
        console.log($scope.Site);
});
```

I don't understand why `$scope.Site` is available in `Success` function but outside (`$http`) `$scope.Site` is `null`.
Please explain for me what happen here.

I'm new to `AngularJS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it yet but apparently the fact that your're returning a value from $http `$scope.Site = $http.get(... //its worng`  and as Valerij said the nature of $http is ajax meaning asynchronous result, causes this bug.

you need to use it like this:

```
 app.controller('SiteDetailCtrl',function($scope, $routeParams, $http){
    //remove ":" in SiteId
    var SiteId = $routeParams.SiteId.replace(':','');

    $http.get('path-to-ajax/Site/'+SiteId);
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.Site = data;
            console.log($scope.Site);
        })
        .error(function(){
            $scope.Site = 'NULL';
            alert('Ajax Fail');
        });
       // console.log($scope.Site);
});
```

html:

```
{{$scope.Site}} //this will work,  asynchronously get results after Success function
```

Comment: Returned data struct is {'SiteName' : 'The name', 'Description' : 'Some desciption'}.
 It mean: $scope.Site = {'SiteName' : 'The name', 'Description' : 'Some desciption'}
My html:
<input type="text" ng-model="SiteName" value="{{$scope.Site.SiteName}}"/> and <input type="text" ng-model="Description" placeholder="Description" value="{{$scope.Site.Description}}"/>

Why doesn't it display?

Comment: you don't need to use $scope in html and you also don"t need to add value you only need ngModel, example: http://jsfiddle.net/choroshin/mqU6z/2/

Comment: Ok, thank you. I find out why I'm wrong. In my HTML, I use element value="{{Site.....}}", it's wrong. I've removed it and only use ng-model.

Answer (score 4):

the `success`handler function you define in line 6 will run way later than the `console.log` statement from line 14. it is nothing angular specific but how **asynchronous code** works. i suggest you research a bit in that direction.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot asynchronous in ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Console.log you are using outside is executed immediately when the controller is initialized,

So the $scope.Site is not have a value

but Success function is called after the data is returned from the server, so value is present in the Success function